# Mapping over 2 arrays

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays of objects: `meeting` and `room` and a `Card` component with some fields to be completed by them.

I tried to map over the arrays in order to access the elements from both of them at the same time but it returns the `Card` component six times(the number of the elements in the array of Room)

```
<div className="topCards">
    {room.map((dataObj) => {
        return (
            <div>
                {meeting.map((meetObject) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="item">
                            <Card3
                                className="card3"
                                teamName={meetObject.name}
                                roomName={dataObj.name}
                                time={dataObj.time}
                                data={dataObj.data}
                                capacity={dataObj.capacity}
                            />
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        );
    })}
</div>
```

So, my question is how can I return the Card element with elements from both cards

Comment: `map` function has a second parameter that holds the current index of an item. You can use that value to get the corresponding value of the other array.

Answer (score 2):

What let you think that it would work like that?

Just use the `index` parameter of [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
<div className="topCards">
  <div>
    {meeting.map((meetObject, i) => {
      return (
        <div className="item">
          <Card3
            className="card3"
            teamName={meetObject.name}
            roomName={dataObj[i].name}
            time={dataObj[i].time}
            data={dataObj[i].data}
            capacity={dataObj[i].capacity}
          />
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>
</div>
```